# Remove entries based on another table max entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, join

I have 2 tables, StoreProduct (with the products for sale in each store) and Sales with the sales of each product per store and per day.

```
 _________________        ____________________________________________
|   StoreProduct  |      |                      Sales                 |
-------------------      ----------------------------------------------
|StoreId|ProductId|      |StoreId|ProductId|     Date      | Quantity |
|1      | 1001    |      |1      | 1001    | '2019-04-15'  | 2        |
|1      | 1002    |      |1      | 1002    | '2019-04-15'  | 3        |
|2      | 1001    |      |2      | 1003    | '2019-04-15'  | 1        |
|2      | 1003    |      |1      | 1001    | '2020-04-25'  | 5        |
|2      | 1005    |      |1      | 1002    | '2020-04-25'  | 4        |
-------------------      |2      | 1005    | '2020-04-25'  | 2        |
                         ----------------------------------------------
```

And my objective is to remove products from a store if they haven't sold anything in the past year.

In this example I would delete the entries

```
StoreId ProductId
2       1001  (never sold)
2       1003  (only sold more than a year ago)
```

Its easy to find the ones that have never been sold with a left join.
But how do I check for both the ones that never sold anything and the ones that haven't sold anything the past year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select sp.*
from storeproduct sp
where not exists (select 1
                  from sales s
                  where s.storeid = sp.storeid and s.productid = sp.productid and
                        s.date > dateadd(year, -1, getdate())
                 );
```

If you want to actually delete the rows:

```
delete sp from storeproduct sp
where not exists (select 1
                  from sales s
                  where s.storeid = sp.storeid and s.productid = sp.productid and
                        s.date > dateadd(year, -1, getdate())
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select sp.*
from storeProduct sp
where not exists (
    select 1
    from sales s
    where 
        s.storeId = sp.storeId 
        and s.productId = sp.productId
        and s.date >= datefromparts(year(getdate()) - 1, 1, 1)
        and s.date <  datefromparts(year(getdate()), 1, 1)
)
```

This gives you rows from `salesProduct` where no row exists in `sales` for the same `storeId` and `productId` in the last calendar year (as of today, this means year 2019).